# What was a rabbinic מעיל משי?

Tags: minhag, history, clothing, yekke

In the book מנהגים דק"ק וורמיישא, one of the first simonim notes that the rov and chazzan in Worms should wear a *Seidenmantel* (He: מעיל משי), which the notes explain was rabbinical garb in those days.

What was the rabbinical/cantorial robe of early 18th-century German Jewry, which R' Juspa Schammes references ?

Comment: Consider rephrasing/elaborating. As it is, the q runs like “What color was George Washington’s white horse?”.

Comment: Was most likely the same/similar to the cloak described by Israel Abrahams (Jewish Life in the Middle Ages p. 17) and Shlomo Eidelberg (Jewish Life in Austria.. p. 121).